# How do I go about sealing tiles painted with acrylic ink?

Tags: preservation, ceramics

I have been painting on ceramic tile's with Liquitex acrylic ink. I would like to seal them so that they could be used as coasters. I want to make them impervious to liquid and coffee cup heat. Does anyone have suggestions on sealing the tile's? When I sprayed some Krylon UV clear protector, the ink was reactivated and began to spread. I was thinking of putting some Liquitex gloss medium on the tiles and thin coating them with clear water-based polyurethane. My other alternative was to use art resin but I'm unclear which would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods should work; polyurethane varnish seems to be a fairly standard way of sealing acrylic paint on ceramic (see [this thread on potters.org](http://www.potters.org/subject98910.htm) for example) and Art Resin* claims that 'the heat generated from a hot mug will not damage the resin surface' and that it is suitable for use on ceramics ([ArtResin FAQ](https://www.artresin.com/pages/faq-2-materials), points 24 and 25).

I also stumbled across [some people](https://daycare.com/forum/showthread.php?t=63101) saying that you can bake acrylics in the same way that you can enamels - no guarantees, but you might find that this works for you.

However, given that you've already had some issues with the ink dissolving in the varnish(possibly caused by attempting to varnish before the ink was fully dry) I suggest that you **test your chosen method** on something disposable before you seal your coasters.

*a brand, but the same points should apply to most clear two part epoxy resins

Comment: I tried spraying the tiles with a clear UV coating from Krylon and the tile began to bleed. Really nervous about what to proceed with before I use the polyurethane or the art risen, the tiles need to be set . Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Looks like that spray contains oil based solvents that will attack the ink. The varnish may as well, testing to be sure is the only safe way. Perhaps a top coat of (water based) acrylic sealer or acrylic medium before varnishing will work. Baking them is likely to oxidize the pigment or burn up/melt the acrylic medium.

Answer (score 1):

One of the Box stores will have "Shrink Wrap Bags".  I suggest this as an alternative to a spray or roll on clear because of the bleeding problem you ran into.

The bags, when exposed to heat should conform to the tile and be washable, although I would not pass them through the dishwasher.

Just a though if you cannot find an acrylic or water based spray.

Comment: That is a very smart idea! I used the Krylon UV protector and it did ruin one tile and not the other four. However it can be carcinogenic and can cause severe, permanent nerve damage –  other than that it's a swell product. I could shrink wrap over the tile and then pour on the Art Resin which is a excellent product. The tiles are now heat - coffee cup heat -water  impervious. When I can figure out how to post a picture and I become more adept at doing these tiles and using Dura lar and yupo paper,I will try and post some pictures. Thank you for your help.